# Using the output of one command as the argument for another

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

I am attempting to grep a file and pipe the line number out to

```
vim +{lineNumber} filetoedit
```

unfortunately Vim throws an error saying

> Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal

An example:

```
grep -nF 'Im looking for this' testfile.txt | cut -f1 -d: | xargs vim +{} testfile.tx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command run by `xargs` inherits `stdin` from `xargs`, so its input is connected to the pipe from `cut`, not the terminal.

Assign the result to a variable and use that.

```
line=$(grep -nF 'Im looking for this' testfile.txt | cut -f1 -d: )
vim "+$line" testfile.txt
```

Comment: I think this works only if grep found exactly one line. When we look at the unsuccessful attempt of the OP, he seems to expect several matches, and wants to open a separate instance of `vim` for each match.

Comment: I don't think he's expecting that. It makes little sense to open multiple `vim` instances on the same file. He also didn't use the `xargs` option to run the command separately for each input.

Comment: Indeed, his usage of xargs doesn't make sense. OTOH, from this code he at least seems to expect more than one match (otherwise it would not make sense to use xargs), and I have no idea what should be the effect in this case. My wild guess was that he wanted to have several vims open, each one positioned at a different line. Only the OP can tell us what he had in mind, but as for your solution, I would at least pipe it through `head -n 1` before feeding it into vim.

Comment: I think he was using `xargs` just because that was the only way he knew to turn stdin into arguments, not because he expected multiple of them.

Comment: So it would appear that I have uhh miscalculated the use of Xargs, 

To confirm @barmar I am expecting Vim to only output one line, and I used xargs because it was the only way I knew how to translate output from first command into an argument, exactly as you had mentioned

I am only expecting one result so the data I'm using as an argument for opening vim will be a single INT so this should be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Scottt `xargs` is usually used when you want to turn `stdin` into multiple arguments. If it's just one argument you usually use command substitution.

Comment: Thank you Barmar! By command substitution do you mean Var=`shellcommand`
?

Comment: I mean `var=$(shellcommand)`. You can also dubstitute directly into the `vim` command: `vim "+$(grep...)" testfile.txt`.

Comment: BTW, if you want to ensure that you only get one match, use `-m 1`.